# What precautions are enough to create a sandbox for a scripting language?

Tags: security, script, sandbox

We have an [ongoing discussion](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30731#p254640) to add some functionality to a project by adding scripting support and it's stucked at security concerns.

Think that a language will be used for configuration purposes, so it must be safe enough as `.ini` files from the point of view of the end users. The actions won't depend on any external binaries, only the language's native tools will be allowed.

Doesn't the following restrictions make it secure enough to run untrusted code:

- Restrict network access
- Disable write access completely
- Provide read access for current directory
- Provide read access only for including global libraries

What else is needed to make a scripting language use as "a configuration tool"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Among other things, you have no protection against cache manipulation, branch prediction poisoning, and rowhammer style attacks present, all of which are possible from the language the linked discussion seems to imply using (Python).

Assuming you are indeed talking about using Python, you also need to consider the fact that Python code can load arbitrary libraries and executables itself through multiple mechanisms, some of which are not dependent on read access.  That all needs to be restricted, and you realistically should probably also restrict access to a lot of the standard library modules too (document macros have no business talking to the syslog daemon or fetching account information for example).

Beyond all that, you also need: some way for the user to explicitly disable auto-running this code, with the ideal situation being that they have to explicitly opt-in to running it (if this had been the default behavior in MS Office from the beginning for macros, then quite a few big viruses wouldn't have made it past a few dozen systems being infected).  Additionally, make *absolutely* certain that the write protection includes the document the macro is associated with, otherwise you still have a data exfiltration mechanism.

TBH, Python is actually not that great for this type of thing.  Were it not kind of the point of the discussion in the first place, I would actually suggest using Lua instead, it's a lot better designed for this type of usage, and it's a lot easier to secure (though the stuff mentioned at the top of my answer is still an issue for Lua too).

Comment: To be able to clarify the boundaries: Ignoring the hardware bugs, would it be safe to send the code to a virtual machine (or a separate hardware which would cover hardware bugs), execute it in there and get the results back?

Comment: Assuming that the VM software has no bugs either, then yes, probably.  However, there have been quite a few bugs in many VM managers that were not hardware specific and allowed escaping the VM (or at least making a DoS attack against the host).

Comment: ...and which led me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine_escape